Conditional decorators in typescript & class-validator
I have this class
class A {
  prop1: string | number

  @IsBoolean()
  prop2: boolean
}

I want to add decorators for prop1, based on prop2, I was thinking of something like this:
class A {
  @IsStringIf((obj) => obj.prop2)
  @IsNumberIf((obj) => !obj.prop2)
  prop1: string | number // number when prop2 is false, string when prop2 is true.

  @IsBoolean()
  prop2: boolean
}

